# How to update and delete record in a database if primary key is auto generated

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    SqlConnection  con =  new  SqlConnection (strcon);

    string query = "update BrandSet set BrandName='" 
                   +  this.textBox1.Text  +  "', Ml = '" 
                   + this.textBox2.Text + "', Price='" 
                   +  this.textBox1.Text 
                   +  "' where Id = ";

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, con);

    SqlDataReader adapt;

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        adapt = command.ExecuteReader();
        con.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("Brand Updated Successfully");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
```

I want to know how to assign `Id` to update and delete record.

Comment: You want to update and delete the same record ?

Comment: Are there any other fields that are unique? If not you could do it in 2 steps, one you update everything but the brandname and brandname is used in the where. Then step 2 the other way around.

Comment: Please remove the uppercase in your question. That's yelling and very rude. The simple answer is, you need to append the ID of the record you try to delete to your query string. The complex counter-question is, how does the user know what object she is updating, and where is that data coming from (I assume something is displayed on the screen). So that's where you need to get the ID from.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Also, if you want to execute an `UPDATE` statement, use `.ExecuteNonQuery()`, not `.ExecuteReader()` :...

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are clicking on a button and it is triggering `button2_Click`. There is a `Tag` property available for each control where you can store your custom data about the control. You can use `Tag` to store the `id` of the record that you are loading. I mean, at the time of fetching data from db, fetch the `id` and assign it the control's `Tag` and when clicked on the control, get its id from `Tag`.

```
// assigning Tag value
int id = // assign id
myControl.Tag = id;
```

More details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: thank you every one for your solution. but I want to know how to fetch the Id from database in where condition

Answer (score 0):

You can use CommandArgument in button.

```
<asp:Button ID="button2" runat="server" Text="Button2"  
     OnClick="button2_Click" CommandArgument="ID_Value"/>


private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    if((String)e.CommandArgument != "")
    {
        id = (String)e.CommandArgument;
    }
}
```